# How to find if a specific key is true in Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I have this array and I want to to get a boolean(true) if there is a 'three' that is equal to 9

myArr = [
      {
        apple: 6,
        basket: [
          {
          one: 1,
          two: 2,
          three: 3
          },
          {
          one: 4,
          two: 5,
          three: 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        apple: 9,
        basket: [
          {
          one: 1,
          two: 2,
          three: 3
          },
          {
          one: 4,
          two: 5,
          three: 9
          }
        ]
      }
  ]

What I tried:

```
enter code here

this.myArr.forEach( data => {
      if(data.basket.filter(cur => cur.one === 0 || cur.three === 9)) {
       console.log('true')
      }
    })
```

This always logs true for some reason I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.filter` will always return an *array* of elements which pass the test, and arrays are truthy. Even if no elements pass the test, the array will still be truthy:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3].filter(() => false);
if (arr) {
  console.log('truthy');
}
```

Use `.some` instead, to see if there is at least one element which passes the test:

```js
const myArr = [{
  apple: 6,
  basket: [{
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  }, {
    one: 4,
    two: 5,
    three: 6
  }]
}, {
  apple: 9,
  basket: [{
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
  }, {
    one: 4,
    two: 5,
    three: 9
  }]
}]

myArr.forEach(data => {
  if (data.basket.some(cur => cur.one === 0 || cur.three === 9)) {
    console.log('true');
  }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't some() stop looping if it finds a value that match the condition? Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, but that's what you want, right? As you said: *I want to to get a boolean(true) if there is a 'three' that is equal to 9*

Answer (score 0):

`filter` returns to array and use `find` which will return matched item or null when no match.

In you code, Just change from `filter` to `find` will work fine.

```js
const myArr = [
  {
    apple: 6,
    basket: [
      { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 },
      { one: 4, two: 5, three: 6 }
    ]
  },
  {
    apple: 9,
    basket: [
      { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 },
      { one: 4, two: 5, three: 9 }
    ]
  }
];

const items = myArr.map(data =>
  data.basket.find(cur => cur.one === 0 || cur.three === 9) ? "true" : "false"
);

console.log(items);
```